# Permission required to use UsageStatsManager

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, usagestatsmanager

I'm trying to use UsageStatsManager. I understand that I need to put the following into my Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

However, Eclipse throws the following error when I try that: The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:ignore" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.

How do I declare the permission properly?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your manifest file, you have to add the tools namespace.
You can declare it this way:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

for example in the manifest tag:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
.
.
.
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your `manifest` tag:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```